# Evaluating products in a Galois field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the Galois field $$GF(27)$$
I know that $$x^3+2x+1$$ is irreducible in $$Z_3$$
It follows that $$GF(27)=Z_3[x]/<f>$$
How would I evaluate $$\alpha^2(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)$$ in my Galois field?

Comment: you need to tell us which isormophic copy of GF(27) you are working in.  Any degree 3 irreducible polynomial over GF(3) gives a construction of GF(27) as GF(3)[$\alpha$]=GF(3)[x]/(p(x)) where $\alpha$ is a root of p(x), then you use relations in the quotient ring (given by $p(\alpha)=0$) to compute.

Comment: what, as in the polynomial?

Comment: yep.  The polynomial tells you how to write any power of $\alpha$ 3 or higher as a degree 2 expression in $\alpha$

Comment: Added information @rvitale

Answer (score 1):

If for example you are working over the isomorphic copy $GF(27)=GF(3)[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ You know that $\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$, so your expression would be $$\alpha^3(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=2(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=2(\alpha^4+\alpha^2+1+2\alpha^3+2\alpha^2+2\alpha)=2(\alpha^4+\alpha^2+1)=2(\alpha \alpha^3+\alpha^2+1)=2(\alpha(2(\alpha^2+\alpha+1))+\alpha^2+1)=2(2\alpha^3+2\alpha^2+2\alpha+\alpha^2+1)=2(\alpha^2+2)=2\alpha^2+1$$

Comment: Oh I didn't see that you added that polynomial and changed the expression a bit. My computation is over a different isomorphic field.  You can repeat the method using your relations/element.

Comment: yes, and then for you $\alpha^3=\alpha+2$